# Too greedy Regex problem

Tags: c#, regex, regex-greedy

I need to parse string that looks like in example below:

```
Regex TitleRegex = new Regex(@"[A-Z].* - ([0-9].*) [A-Z]");
var match = TitleRegex.Match("Chapter - 1 The Brown Fox");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

What I want is to extract a number. The problem is that output is `1 The Brown` instead of simply `1`.
I do not understand why letters are also included to the numeric (`[0-9]`) pattern.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex TitleRegex = new Regex(@"[A-Z].* - ([0-9]{1,2}) [A-Z]");
```

You are capturing the `.` which generally is *match all except new lines*. I put the `{1,2}` quantifier there, meaning it will match 0-99. Change that to suit your requirements (or you could just leave it as *0 or more* `*`).

Could you also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. Shorthand is generally a good thing :)

Comment: Thank you! It was a stupid copy-paste mistake. I've broken my head working around this %)

Answer (score 2):

The letters are included because you asked for them when you added `.*` to the capture group. Try just `([0-9]+)` or better `(\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you appear to be misusing the quantifiers;

```
[0-9].*
```

That partial pattern matches any single digit (0-9) once, and then *also* any character at all (.) 0 or more times (*)

Remove the dots before the asterisks.

```
[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
"[A-Z].* - ([0-9]?) [A-Z]"
```

When you use `[0-9].*` it searches for one number plus 0 or many symbols, using `[0-9]+` gives you one or more integers on that specific place. If you are sure there wont be more than lets say 3 integers so you can use `[0-9]{1,3}` or as much as you want 4,5,etc.